# Как я могу получить int из string?

Tags: java, строки

Есть такой кусочек кода. По bluetooth я получаю строку с двумя переменными, разделяю их по пайпу, потом каждую переменную по отдельности показываю на экране, все прекрасно работает. Но как видите, я пытаюсь использовать `teta=Integer.parseInt(var[0]);` для того, чтобы повернуть `ImageView trailer`. Хотя `setRotation` вроде float просит, но и int у меня кушает хорошо. `int teta;` объявлена ранее

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String text = intent.getStringExtra("theMessage");
        TextView fi_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fi_text);
        TextView teta_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.teta_text);

        String var[]=text.split("\\|");
        teta_text.setText(var[0]); //teta значение с bt
        teta=Integer.parseInt(var[0]);
        fi_text.setText(var[1]); //fi значение с bt


        trailer.setRotation(teta);
    }

};
```

Я уверен, что проблема именно в этом, и что я неправильно пользуюсь этой функцией) Как я могу сделать, чтобы int переменную можно было здесь использовать и чтобы приложение не падало?

Использую `parseInt` по причине того, что нашел такую штуку и она работает `int i = Integer.parseInt("234");`. А как с переменной работать не знаю, не нашел ничего нужного
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Я уверен, что проблема именно в этом ...` О какой проблеме идет речь? Что происходит не так?

Comment: @defaultlocale Дополнил пост. Речь о том, что если добавляю переменную в Integer.parseInt(переменная); , то приложение падает. Если туда помещать текст в "", то все работает хорошо

Comment: А каким образом оно падает? Какое возникает исключение?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста пример строки на которой падает приложение

Comment: @defaultlocale добавил скрин. падает как раз из-за строчки teta=Integer.parseInt(var[0]);

Comment: Спасибо, стало яснее. Будет еще лучше если Вы вставите сообщение об ошибке в виде текста в сам вопрос. И присоединяюсь к просьбе ZMS показать входную строку.

Comment: @defaultlocale не совсем вас понял. показать какую строку? если закомментировать teta=Integer.parseInt(var[0]); и trailer.setRotation(teta); соответственно, то все работает хорошо. я попробую потыкать сам сейчас. просто хотелось узнать, что я правильно использую функцию parseInt. возможно, ошибка не здесь

Comment: Покажите какое значение принимают переменные `text` и `var[0]` перед тем как падает приложение.

Comment: С вызовом `parseInt` все норм. Ошибка говорит о том, что в него передается некорректная строка. Для ответа нужно понять какая это строка. Я вижу два варианта: 1) строка содержит нечисловые символы (буквы, кракозябры) и тогда нужно решать что из них нужно получить и как; 2) строка содержит вещественное число и тогда нужно использовать другой метод.

Comment: @defaultlocale, на скрине видно строку в исключении. Возможно, это какой-то BOM, либо файл открыт не в той кодировке.

Comment: @defaultlocale text принимает значения от -99|-99 до 99|99, это два значения с двух датчиков. соответственно значение var[0] от -99 до 99. кстати, насчет кракозябр. в логе кракозябры проскакивают, а вот в текствью все чисто приходит. я даже не думал об этом

Comment: @Qwertiy угу, поэтому автору нужно логи в виде текста приложить, чтобы можно было понять что там за зверь.

Comment: @CottonPericranium ну для начала нужно понять что там: посмотрите значение в режиме отладки, либо в логи выведите.

Comment: @defaultlocale, квадрат, вопрос, вопрос - после копипаста от них ничего не останется. Тогда уж hex-дамп нужен, но проще просто подебажить код...

Comment: @defaultlocale каким образом здесь выложит логи? просто текстом? увидел интересную строчку E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe

Comment: @CottonPericranium текстом

Comment: @defaultlocale это нечитабельно совсем получается. ладно, я пойду потыкаю сам. думаю, что все таки это из-за кракозябр. но тогда непонятно, почему их текствью не показывает.

Comment: @defaultlocale спасибо за наводку) кракозябры хоть и не видно на экране приложения, но они оказываются отлично убираются с помощью var[0].substring(1); проблема решена

Answer (score 1):

И все-таки да, виной всему кракозябры. В любом случае, ответ получен, спасибо за помощь.

Поскольку проблема оказалась в том, что по bluetooth каналу мне приходили кракозябры, их было хорошо видно в логах и они всегда стояли впереди и в конце сообщения, количество их не изменялось, то я просто перед отправкой на другое активити, где происходит дальнейшая обработка этих данных, удалил эти кракозябры функцией `substring`.

```
while (true) {
            // Read from the InputStream
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);

                Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");
                incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("theMessage", incomingMessage.substring(2, incomingMessage.length()-1));
                //удаляю кракозябры

                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/191464)

Comment: @kizoso это и есть автор вопроса, саммого себя просить внести уточнения мало смысла.

Comment: @Cotton Pericranium добавте в ответ фрагмент кода с изменениями, которые решили вашу проблему.